# Is there any paper about the encoding process in the machine learning API?

Tags: q#

I want to know more details about the encoding process in machine learning. I have read the source code about the "ApproximateInputEncoder" method. It seems like a complex method. So is there any paper or document to explain the mechanism in detail of the encoding process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QDK machine learning library is based on the paper ['Circuit-centric quantum classifiers', Maria Schuld, Alex Bocharov, Krysta Svore and Nathan Wiebe](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00633), I would start looking for details there. Section A "State preparation" mentions preparing the input states and some references for the routines that can be used.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the paper "Circuit-centric quantum classifiers", Section A doesn't seem to provide much information. Maybe I need to read the references paper. Thanks again.